# Refresh entire contents of div container upon a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using a sports WordPress plugin that generates content for that sport based on shortcode that is placed in a page. Right now it is set up by default so that you have to set up a page for every sport and insert that sports shortcode but what I am trying to do is set up a dropdown menu instead on one single page that lists all the sports and upon selection it will display the generated shortcode data for that sport.

The problem I am running into is the data does not refresh or even regenerate upon a new selection from the dropdown. In fact upon selecting the first dropdown it does display generated content but it is random content and I have no idea why. I placed each type of short code in it's own div container and the div does switch out the titles of the sports upon selection but the data does not change or even load. Do I just need the div to refresh as if someone was clicking on a new link to a page to get the content to load? Not sure what I am missing. Can someone please take a look and help me out? Thanks!

I included all the code just for reference sake and here is the current url of what is happening: https://wsplays-members.com/results/ Obviously a membership is needed to view any specific sport content but the php generated message should still display upon selecting any sport and right now it only does for the first menu selection. Again thank you.

Wordpress page code:

```
<select class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
    <option value="">Select a sport</option>
    <option value="content_1" data-show=".nfl-results">NFL Football</option>
    <option value="content_2" data-show=".ncaafoot-results">NCAA Football</option>
    <option value="content_3" data-show=".cfl-results">CFL Football</option>
    <option value="content_4" data-show=".nba-results">NBA Basketball</option>
    <option value="content_5" data-show=".ncaabasket-results">NCAA Basketball</option>
    <option value="content_6" data-show=".mlb-results">MLB Baseball</option>
<select>

<div class="my-info-1">
<div id="content_1" class="nfl-results inv">
<!--AUTHORIZED TO VIEW NFL Football DETAILED PICKS RECORDS CONTENT GO HERE-->
[membership level="1,2,3,12,23,37,41,42,44,45,46,47"]
[get_biddata type='current' sport='NFL Football'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='past' sport='NFL Football'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='detailed' sport='NFL Football'][/get_biddata]
[/membership]
<!--HIDE DEFAULT MESSAGE FOR ALL LEVELS WHEN LOGGED IN-->
[membership]
[get_biddata type='defaultMessage' sport='NFL Football'][/get_biddata]
</div>

<div id="content_2" class="ncaafoot-results inv">
<!--AUTHORIZED TO VIEW NCAA Football DETAILED PICKS RECORDS CONTENT GO HERE-->
[membership level="1,2,3,12,23,37,41,42,44,45,46,47"]
[get_biddata type='current' sport='NCAA Football'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='past' sport='NCAA Football'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='detailed' sport='NCAA Football'][/get_biddata]
[/membership]
<!--HIDE DEFAULT MESSAGE FOR ALL LEVELS WHEN LOGGED IN-->
[membership]
[get_biddata type='defaultMessage' sport='NCAA Football'][/get_biddata]
</div>

<div id="content_3" class="cfl-results inv">
<!--AUTHORIZED TO VIEW CFL Football DETAILED PICKS RECORDS CONTENT GO HERE-->
[membership level="1,2,3,12,23,37,41,42,44,45,46,47"]
[get_biddata type='current' sport='CFL Football'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='past' sport='CFL Football'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='detailed' sport='CFL Football'][/get_biddata]
[/membership]
<!--HIDE DEFAULT MESSAGE FOR ALL LEVELS WHEN LOGGED IN-->
[membership]
[get_biddata type='defaultMessage' sport='CFL Football'][/get_biddata]
</div>

<div id="content_4" class="nba-results inv">
<!--AUTHORIZED TO VIEW NBA Basketball DETAILED PICKS RECORDS CONTENT GO HERE-->
[membership level="1,2,3,12,23,37,41,42,44,45,46,47"]
[get_biddata type='current' sport='NBA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='past' sport='NBA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='detailed' sport='NBA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
[/membership]
<!--HIDE DEFAULT MESSAGE FOR ALL LEVELS WHEN LOGGED IN-->
[membership]
[get_biddata type='defaultMessage' sport='NBA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
</div>

<div id="content_5" class="ncaabasket-results inv">
<!--AUTHORIZED TO VIEW NCAA Basketball DETAILED PICKS RECORDS CONTENT GO HERE-->
[membership level="1,2,3,12,23,37,41,42,44,45,46,47"]
[get_biddata type='current' sport='NCAA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='past' sport='NCAA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='detailed' sport='NCAA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
[/membership]
<!--HIDE DEFAULT MESSAGE FOR ALL LEVELS WHEN LOGGED IN-->
[membership]
[get_biddata type='defaultMessage' sport='NCAA Basketball'][/get_biddata]
</div>

<div id="content_6" class="mlb-results inv">
<!--AUTHORIZED TO VIEW MLB Baseball DETAILED PICKS RECORDS CONTENT GO HERE-->
[membership level="1,2,3,12,23,37,41,42,44,45,46,47"]
[get_biddata type='current' sport='MLB Baseball'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='past' sport='MLB Baseball'][/get_biddata]
[get_biddata type='detailed' sport='MLB Baseball'][/get_biddata]
[/membership]
<!--HIDE DEFAULT MESSAGE FOR ALL LEVELS WHEN LOGGED IN-->
[membership]
[get_biddata type='defaultMessage' sport='MLB Baseball'][/get_biddata]
</div>
</div>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
function memberresults($sport_val,$data_type){
global $wpdb;
  $bidsys_options = get_option('bidsys_options');
   for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
        if($bidsys_options->sportsstatus[$i]!="Disabled"){
             if($sport_val==$bidsys_options->sportsname[$i])
             $sport = $i;
   }}
  $user = get_current_user_id();
  $currentsportaccess =   get_user_meta($user,"sport_".$sport ,true);
    if($currentsportaccess=="No"){
        ?>
        <div class="pmpro_content_message">Your access plan is valid but does not give you access to view this section.<br /> You may <a href="<?=home_url();?>/purchase/">purchase another access plan here</a>.</div>
        <?php

    } else {


    if($data_type=="current"){
     if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel() ) {
   ?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    memberresults("current","<?php echo $sport;?>","");
});
</script>
<h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
<h2 class="post-title">Current Season</h2>
<table class='inner_result'>
<td colspan='5' >
<table id='member_<?=$data_type;?>season_vals_inner' class='hdr_3 inner_result'>
</table>
</td>
</table>
   <?php
        } else {

            ?>
        <h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
        <h2 class="post-title">Current Season Record</h2>
        <div class="pmpro_content_message">You must be logged in to view this section.  Please <a href="<?=home_url();?>/login/">log in</a> or <a href="<?=home_url();?>/register/">register here</a>.</div>
        <?php

        }
    } else  if($data_type=="past"){
     if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel() ) {

    $result = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bidsys_sport_seasons WHERE sport=  '".$sport."' AND current_season = 'NO'   ORDER BY start_date DESC";
     $newmeta = $wpdb->get_results($result);
    ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    memberresults("past","<?php echo $sport;?>","season_<?php echo $newmeta[0]->id;?>");
});
</script>
<h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
<h2 class="post-title">Previous Seasons</h2>
    <form action='' method='post' class="f_p_filter_frm outside_table">
    <select  name='f_p_filter' class="f_p_filter" onchange='memberresults("past","<?php echo $sport; ?>",this.value)' >
    <?php $i = 0; foreach($newmeta as $seasons ){
        if($i == 0){  $sel =  'selected=""'; } else { $sel = ""; }
        ?>
    <option value='season_<?php echo $seasons->id;?>' <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo $seasons->season_name;?></option>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
    </select>
    </form>

<table class='inner_result'>
<td colspan='5' >
<table id='member_<?=$data_type;?>season_vals_inner' class='hdr_3'>
</table>
</td>
</table>
   <?php
        } else {

            ?>
        <h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
        <h2 class="post-title">Previous Seasons Records</h2>
        <div class="pmpro_content_message">You must be logged in to view this section.  Please <a href="<?=home_url();?>/login/">log in</a> or <a href="<?=home_url();?>/register/">register here</a>.</div>
        <?php

        }

    } else  if($data_type=="detailed"){
     if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel() ) {
   ?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    memberresults("detailed","<?php echo $sport;?>","yesterday");
});
</script>
<style>
.imgwin {
    background: url('/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/winningPick.gif');
     height: 16px; width: 16px; margin:8px;
}
.imgloss {
    background: url('/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/losingPick.gif');
     height: 16px;  width: 16px;  margin:8px;
}
.imgpush {
    background: url('/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/pushedPick.gif');
     height: 16px;  width: 16px; margin:8px;
}

</style>
<h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
<h2 class="post-title">Detailed History</h2>
<form action='' method='post' class="f_p_filter_frm outside_table">
    <select  name='f_p_filter' class="f_p_filter" onchange='memberresults("detailed","<?php echo $sport; ?>",this.value)' >
    <?php
    $result = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bidsys_sport_seasons WHERE sport=  '".$sport."' AND current_season = 'NO'   ORDER BY start_date DESC";
     $newmeta = $wpdb->get_results($result);

    foreach($newmeta as $seasons ){
        ?>
    <option value='season_<?php echo $seasons->id;?>' ><?php echo $seasons->season_name;?></option>
    <?php  }
    ?>
    <option value='playoftheday30' >Play of the Day (L30 Days)</option>
    <option value='playoftheday365' >Play of the Day (L365 Days)</option>
    <option value='latebreakingplay30' >VIP Late Info Play (L30 Days)</option>
    <option value='latebreakingplay365' >VIP Late Info Play (L365 Days)</option>
    <option value='vipplays30' >VIP Plays (L30 Days)</option>
    <option value='vipplays365' >VIP Plays (L365 Days)</option>
    <option value='yesterday' selected="">Yesterday</option>
    <option value='past7days' >Past 7 Days</option>
    <option value='past30days' >Past 30 Days</option>
    <option value='current' >Current Season</option>
    <option value='past365days' >Past 365 Days</option>
    </select>
    </form>
<div style="width: 56px; float: right; background: #F8F8F8;"><img src="/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/pushedPick.gif" />  Push</div><div style=" margin: -2px 3% 0; padding-bottom: 2px; float: right;">|</div>
<div style="width: 56px; float: right; background: #F8F8F8;"><img src="/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/losingPick.gif" />  Loss</div><div style=" margin: -2px 3% 0; padding-bottom: 2px; float: right;">|</div>
<div style="width: 48px; float: right; background: #F8F8F8;"><img src="/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/winningPick.gif" />  Win</div>
<table class='inner_result detailed_history'> 
<tr class="hdr_2">
<td>Game Date</td>
<td colspan="2">Game/Pick Details</td>
<td>Result</td>
<td>Unit Change</td>
</tr>
<table id='member_<?=$data_type;?>season_vals_inner' class='hdr_3'>
</table>
</table>
   <?php
        } else {

            ?>
        <h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
        <h2 class="post-title">Detailed History</h2>
        <div class="pmpro_content_message">You must be logged in to view this section.  Please <a href="<?=home_url();?>/login/">log in</a> or <a href="<?=home_url();?>/register/">register here</a>.</div>
        <?php

        }

    } else  if($data_type=="pending"){
      if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel() ) {
   ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    memberresults("pending","<?php echo $sport;?>","");
});
</script>
<h1 class="post-title">Today's <?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
<table id='member_<?=$data_type;?>season_vals_inner' class='hdr_3'>
</table>
   <?php 
      }
        } else  if($data_type=="unauthorized"){
            if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel() ) {
        ?>
<h1 class="post-title">Today's <?php echo $sport_val; ?> Picks</h1>
<div class="members-only">
Picks posted here are for <strong>PAID MEMBERS ONLY</strong>.<br> Your current membership level is not authorized to view this section.</strong><br> <a href="<?=home_url();?>/subscription-options/">Click Here</a> to upgrade your membership and view today's <?php echo $sport_val; ?> picks.</p></div>
        <?php
        }
      }

        else if($data_type=="defaultMessage"){
            if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel() ) {
        ?>
        <!--INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK SO WHEN A MEMBER LOGS IN THE MESSAGE BELOW DISAPPEARS-->
        <?php

        } else {

        ?>
<div class="loggedout-members-only">
<p>Picks posted here are for <strong>PAID MEMBERS ONLY</strong>.<br>
<a href="http://wsplays-members.com/login/">Log In</a> &nbsp;-<strong>or</strong>-&nbsp; <a href="http://wsplays-members.com/subscription-options/">View/Purchase Subscriptions Here</a>.</p>
<p><a href="http://wsplays-members.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level=23">Click Here</a> to register for <strong>FREE PICKS</strong> and gain <strong>FREE ACCESS</strong><br> to our Pick History &amp; Detailed Records </p>
</div>
        <?php
        }
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Sports Plugin Javascript file

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
var memberresults =
        function memberresults(seasontype, sport, seasonrange) {
            "use strict";
            var ajaxl = '<img src="/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />',
                dataURL = "seasontype=" + seasontype + "&sport=" + sport + "&seasonrange=" + seasonrange;
            jQuery("#member_" + seasontype + "season_vals_inner").html(ajaxl);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/ajax_member.php",
                data: dataURL,
                success: function (msg) {  // alert(msg);
                    jQuery("#member_" + seasontype + "season_vals_inner").html(msg);
                }
            });
        };

var filterresult =
         function filterresult(type, val) {
            "use strict";
            var ajaxl = '<img src="/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/customgif/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />',
                dataURL = "action=" + type + "&val=" + val;
            jQuery("#" + type + "_vals").html(ajaxl);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/wp-content/plugins/bid-sys/ajax_load.php",
                data: dataURL,
                success: function (msg) {  // alert(msg);
                    jQuery("#" + type + "_vals").html(msg);
                }
            });
        };

filterresult("overall", "playoftheday365");
filterresult("persport", "currentseason");
// END

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
// backend script for rp_picks.php
    "use strict";
    jQuery("select.f_p_filter").uniform();
    jQuery(".validatenm").bind("keyup change", function () {
        if (!(this.value).match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d){0,1}$/) && this.value !== "") {
            jQuery(this).addClass('errorfield');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('errorfield');
        }
    });
// END
```

My added javascript file

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function () {
        var target = $(this).data('target'),
            show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
        $(target).children().addClass('inv');
        $(show).removeClass('inv');
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Added to CSS file

```
.inv {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: You say "the data does not refresh or even regenerate". Do you mean to say that the shortcodes are supposed to dynamically generate/update content via ajax (on demand)? Or should everything be there after pageload, and the dropdown is only for switching which content is visible?

Comment: Actually, there's supposed to be divs with id content_1, content_2, etc on the page, and only the first one is there. The rest isn't there except some of the html comments. I'd say something's wrong with the shortcodes. Did the plugins instructions tell you to use endtags?`[/get_biddata]` `[/membership]` If all is ok check the php error logs. You can also enable [wp_debug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: The short codes generate and update fine when placed on separate pages and they are of the same sport. But when I try to list them all on one page in separate div containers per sport they dont work and do not seem to separate. The first div loads but loads random generated php content. All the titles load the way they should it's just the javascript content I think.

Comment: If the code all loaded up at once and generated the content for all the divs and just kept them hidden until selected I could accept that too. Just doesn't happen

Comment: Well, I am now getting those content divs, so something changed...

Comment: All I did was move the code from the wordpress page into a php file and made a short code to insert into the wordpress page itself. If you care to login with a sample free account and see for yourself that would be much appreciated. Of course you would need to copy and paste the url https://wsplays-members.com/results/ once logged in because there currently is no link to it. Then you can really see what is going on. You can use this temp login Username = test and Password = password Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141863/discussion-between-yezzz-and-dambr7).

Answer (score 1):

Fix for your added JS file

```
$('.div-toggle').on('change', function() {
      $('.my-info-1').children().addClass('inv');
      $('#'+this.value).removeClass('inv');
});
```

Alternatively

```
$('.div-toggle').on('change', function() {
      $('.my-info-1').children().hide();
      $('#'+this.value).show(100);
});
```

Comment: I tried several ways to integrate this code including replacing all my code with it. Is that what you intended I try? Either way it still did not work for me but thank you for trying. It actually loaded all of the divs onto the page at once.

Comment: @Dambr7 I had a mistake with code, fixed it. Can you try again? I also added alternative method. I'd rather use alternative method, which also adds animation effect on display.

Comment: @Dambr7 please also comment all lines in your previous added JS file, so they don't effect the result.

Comment: Thank you again for trying to help me out. This does work however it just loads up the divs and the titles. The actual specific content that should be generated by the shortcode does not show up when you click on a selection from the drop down. I'm pretty sure it may have something to do with the javascript of the sports plugin under `var memberresults` or within the php file. When you place the shortcode of one sport `[get_biddata type='current' sport='NCAA Football']` on separate pages it works fine. I'm trying to get them all on one page in a dropdown.

Comment: Seems when you have multiple short codes with `sport =` that have the same `type=` things do not work and I'm not sure why or how to fix this or if there is a work around to get the divs to unload and reload upon selection to make them refresh the entire contents as if going to a new page itself possibly?

Comment: If you like you can use this temp login Username = test and Password = password to see whats happening on the page itself. You'll have to copy and paste this url once logged in though since the page is not an active page on the site. https://wsplays-members.com/results/

Comment: @Dambr7 shortcodes are rendered on page load. After page is loaded, you can't change it. I suppose you are trying to show the user a content, depending on his login status. If so, right way to do this, for users not logged in -> only display membership/login links. For users logged in -> display member content . I guess you are trying to do both at same time, that is where the problem at.